# ffplay with cookies

Tags: ffmpeg

Normally with ffplay you can play a video like this

```
ffplay http://easy.com/foo.flv
```

However I have come across a video that requires a cookie. wget has no trouble with this

```
wget http://hard.com/foo.flv --load-cookies cookies.txt
```

Can ffplay play a video that requires a cookie?

Based on [pogorskiy’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13679431) this works

```sh
ffplay -headers $'Cookie: sbsession=sbg&sbuser=lorem\r\n' http://hard.com/foo.flv
```

Comment: MPlayer can do it. See [here](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=MPlayer_youtube_script).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an option `-headers` in the http protocol. Thus we could write

```sh
ffplay http://easy.com/foo.flv -headers "Cookie: MyCookies"
```

But ffmpeg requires sequence `\r\n` in additional headers. Otherwise you will get a warning

`[http @ 011701a0] No trailing CRLF found in HTTP header.`

and the headers are added incorrectly. We can not pass properly CRLF sequence through command line. I think the only solution would be to fix `http.c` so that the pre-defined characters is replaced by CRLF.

Answer (score 3):

actually you can test this in shell

```
$ echo 0$'\r\n'0
0
0
```

so, add $'\r\n' at the end of header strings

```
ffplay http://easy.com/foo.flv -headers "Cookie: MyCookies"$'\r\n'
```

and ffplay will got non string \r\n.
it works in my ffmpeg version `ffmpeg version git-2014-09-24-857fc0a`

Answer (score 0):

Based on [pogorskiy’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13679431) this works for me with Bash

```sh
set 'sbsession=sbg&sbuser=lorem' 'http://hard.com/foo.flv'
printf -v q 'Cookie: %s\r\n' "$1"
ffplay -headers "$q" "$2"
```